# waiting for network configuration network manager

Tags: networking, network-manager, connection

I recently updated ubuntu to 12.04 and i have 2 problems:

1.)  'waiting for network configuration'  shows each time when starting computer

2.) I always have to type in terminal 'sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager start' in order to get wireless connection working. How to configure to start it automatically with startup?

Please help me to solve these 2 problems.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

*I solved **second problem** in the way mentioned below.*

In terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Above the `exit 0` line add:

```
/etc/init.d/network-manager start
```

Saved the new file and close gedit, reboot to test.